Using scrapy module to scrape a website yields 403 error
I created a spider using the Scrapy module in Python that works; however, I am being blocked at a certain point when running the spider. I investigated and learned that to prevent this from happening, I can use the settings to enable middlewares that allow creating fake user agents and a different proxy IP for each request. However, even after implementing this, I still receive a 403 error at a certain point.
here is my implementation of the middlewares:
class ScrapeOpsFakeUserAgentMiddleware:
@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    return cls(crawler.settings)

def __init__(self, settings):
    self.scrapeops_api_key = settings.get('SCRAPEOPS_API_KEY')
    self.scrapeops_endpoint = settings.get('SCRAPEOPS_FAKE_USER_AGENT_ENDPOINT', 'http://headers.scrapeops.io/v1/user-agents?') 
    self.scrapeops_fake_user_agents_active = settings.get('SCRAPEOPS_FAKE_USER_AGENT_ENABLED', False)
    self.scrapeops_num_results = settings.get('SCRAPEOPS_NUM_RESULTS')
    self.headers_list = []
    self._get_user_agents_list()
    self._scrapeops_fake_user_agents_enabled()

def _get_user_agents_list(self):
    payload = {'api_key': self.scrapeops_api_key}
    if self.scrapeops_num_results is not None:
        payload['num_results'] = self.scrapeops_num_results
    response = requests.get(self.scrapeops_endpoint, params=urlencode(payload))
    json_response = response.json()
    self.user_agents_list = json_response.get('result', [])

def _get_random_user_agent(self):
    random_index = random.randint(0, len(self.user_agents_list) - 1)
    return self.user_agents_list[random_index]

def _scrapeops_fake_user_agents_enabled(self):
    if self.scrapeops_api_key is None or self.scrapeops_api_key == '' or self.scrapeops_fake_user_agents_active == False:
        self.scrapeops_fake_user_agents_active = False
    self.scrapeops_fake_user_agents_active = True

def process_request(self, request, spider):        
    random_user_agent = self._get_random_user_agent()
    request.headers['User-Agent'] = random_user_agent

class RandomProxyMiddleware:
def __init__(self, settings):
    self.proxies = settings.get('ROTATING_PROXY_LIST', [])

@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    return cls(crawler.settings)

def process_request(self, request, spider):
    if not self.proxies:
        return
    
    proxy = random.choice(self.proxies)
    request.meta['proxy'] = proxy

Can someone help me find a solution for this?

The 403 status code is usually because the website rejected your request.
If the website don't need login or temporary cookies, you can use a dynamic proxy. If accounts are involved, you can purchase multiple accounts, and bind each account to a residential IP, and then crawl it.
